# Getting error while refreshing page in magento 2.3

Tags: error, xampp

### When I have installed Magento 2.3 it's working fine. I have added categories, subcategories, products successfully. But Accidentally its showing error as below :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access property ReflectionParameter::$name in F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php:25 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php(25): ReflectionFunctionAbstract->getParameters() #1 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime.php(49): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...') #2 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\Framewo...') #3 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...') #4 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewo...') #5 F:\xampp\ht in F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php on line 25

---

Please help me what can I do to solve it?
PHP version : 7.1.28

Note: I'm new to Magento. Today I have started to learn it.

Comment: Just i have tried to restart Xampp and run again magento storefront then showing error as below:  
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 959719884189

Comment: execute command " rm -rf generated/* var/view_preprocessed/* " then refresh the page

Comment: copy the error record number and go to var/log/report find the error file with the same number and check the error.

Comment: thank you so much @AnandOntigeri . It's working now

Comment: is that working?

Comment: i am adding my comment in answer section please accept the answer, if it is working means

Comment: @AnandOntigeri what is the meaning of this command rm -rf generated/* var/view_preprocessed/* and why need to remove it?

Comment: once you add new files or change in the file we need proper file to be updated in generation folder , rm -rf is unix command to remove the files from the mentioned folder once you remove the files, whenever you refresh the page the files will re generates again means you will see the updated files in generation folder in magento 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

execute command "`rm -rf generated/* var/view_preprocessed/*`" and refresh the page.